# Identification of unknown peltier element

Tags: peltier

I recently found an old, unused peltier element in our lab, with dimensions 40x40x4 mm³. Unfortunately, no type number is visible on it. By connecting it to a power supply I could identify the hot and cold side, but I do not know anything about the maximum current and voltage. Unfortunately, due to a lack of camera I can not add a picture of it here.
Based on other equipment used in the lab I suspect that it could be one of the elements listed here: https://customthermoelectric.com/products/thermoelectric-coolers-tecs/standard-tecs.html?dim_a_group=10&dim_b_group=17
but none of the elements there fit the dimensions.
Are there other approaches to determine the maximum voltage/current and the maximum power of the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare it to a number of commercial 40 x 40 x 4mm TECs and your sample will probably fall in the middle somewhere. You won't likely be able to determine if it is a high-temperature type non-destructively.

Alternatively, have your accounting folks search for a few key words and see if it pops up on a Purchase Order. In particular, have them look for POs from (or mentioning) the company you suspect. It may be a discontinued item.

Comment: It could also have been a part of a larger cooling unit where it was extracted and removed, which would make the second suggestion difficult, unfortunately

Comment: @arc_lupus That does not fit with your description of "unused".

Comment: @SpehroPfhany: Unused with respect to "Currently not in use", not "Has never been in use before", I apologize for that confusion.